# Loading more posts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am adding a LoadMore function to append more posts based on the length of current displayed posts and total posts in DOM. The issue I am having is when I console log the listofposts and I inspect the element in Google Chrome, I see the length is showing zero (0). I am not sure exactly where I have gone wrong or if the aproach I have taken is right or should I separate the two functions by first loading the first 4 posts, then create a new function separate to handle the appending?

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {     
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=recentstories&callback=",
            dataType: "json",
            jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); },
            complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); },
            success:function(data){

            var $listofposts = $('data');
            console.log($listofposts);
            var $loadMore = $listofposts.parent().find('.load-more');
           //   console.log($loadMore);

            currentPage = 0;
            postsPerPage = 4;

            var showMorePosts = function () {

                $offset = currentPage * postsPerPage, //initial value is 0

                    posts = data.posts.slice($offset, $offset + postsPerPage);
                    console.log(posts);
                    $.each(posts, function(i, val) {
                    //console.log(val);
                    $("#postlist").html();
                    var result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
                    $('#postlist').append(result);
                    console.log(result);
                    });

                    if(posts.length !== postsPerPage){
                        alert ('True');
                        $loadMore.hide();
                    }

                    currentPage++;
                    $("#postlist").listview();
                    $("#postlist").listview('refresh');
                    }

                    showMorePosts();
                    $loadMore.on('click', showMorePosts);

                }});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $listofposts = $('data');
```

is asking jQuery for a list of all `<data>` tags in the document.
You might want to use `$(data)` instead.

Comment: Ah I think I must be sleeping. That's correct. Just one more for now, how do I display the element 'count' since it inside the object element. The length is currently showing 1 but count is showing the exact amount of posts 11

Comment: I think you will want to find the HTML element where you want to display the post count and call something like `text(data.count)` on its jQuery object.

Comment: How do I achieve this. Still new to Jquery

Comment: You need to able to find the element where you want to display the post count, so let's give it an id (e.g. `postCount`). We can now search for it using jQuery (`$('#postCount')`) and overwrite the text it contains: `$('#postCount').text(data.count);`. Keep in mind that you have to do this somewhere in your code where you have access to your `data` object.

Comment: OK I will try this out and let you know